# R Shiny - Access an App on my Local Machine

Tags: r, shiny, lan

I can not avoid windows at work.  As such, I have a second machine that I use to do all of my heavy lifting and data analysis.  In an ideal world, I could create a Shiny app and access it from another computer on my work's local network.

The solution that my IT folks proposed was using Remote Desktop, which COULD work, but I don't really want other users locking the machine.

Does anyone have insight as to how I can allow computers on my network to view my Shiny apps? I should have admin rights on my 2nd machine in case I need to tweak a few settings.

**EDIT:**  While my ideal use case is Shiny, I would also want to access other R-based reports like Slidify presentations, compiled R Markdown reports, and perhaps, Gitbooks compiled to stand-alone websites.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be sufficient to set the host argument to 0.0.0.0 to allow it to broadcast beyond localhost, e.g.

```
runApp("app_name",host="0.0.0.0",port=3168)
```

Then you can visit `http://machine2DNSname:3168` to see it.

Comment: Boom!  That was it.  I was not running it with the host parameter.

Comment: Do you need to configure any settings for this in any of the two computers? I have 2 windows computers on a network. I want my colleague to access my apps. I tried the above and it shows "This page can’t be displayed" on the browser. any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I can't duplicate your setup, but you almost certainly need to open a port in the firewall of the serving machine. You can temporarily take the firewall down entirely to see if that's the problem.