# Configure shiny runtime option on flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to access a flexdashboard from another machine in my local network (both windows machines).

From this [this post](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/425) I found out shiny behavior was changed to avoid this by default starting from version 0.9.0. For a shiny application only, this could be easily done setting the `host` option when calling `runApp` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065981/r-shiny-access-an-app-on-my-local-machine)):

```
runApp("app_name",host="0.0.0.0",port=3168)
```

Is there a way to specify `host` paramenter on a flexdashboard header? Or alternatively configure shiny to use a specific host by defult? The header of my current flexdashboard is:

```
---
title: "My analysis"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765996/r-markdown-with-shiny-server-change-host-parameter) should help you.

Comment: Thank you @NicE, indeed, doing that helped to shed some light into the problem, but did not solve it. When I run [a simple shiny app](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/084-single-file/app.R) I am able to access from the other machine. I also get this in the console: > shiny::runApp()
Loading required package: shiny
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3721 . However if I run the flexdashboard I get this in the R Markdown tab on RStudio: Loading required package: shiny  Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5419. It looks like the flexdashboard ignored `options(shiny.host="0.0.0.0")`

Comment: are you running it using `Running document` in Rstudio. As the answer states that wouldn't work. It only works if you run your flex_dashboard by running  `options(shiny.host="0.0.0.0"); rmarkdown::run("myfile.Rmd")` in the console. I did a quick test and it runs fine.

Comment: @NicE, you were right, I missed the `Running document` warning when I skimmed thourgh the answer. That solved the issue! Essentially it was a "how to configure shiny on a specific session" issue instead of a flexdashboard one. If you make this into an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Glad it worked, you can upvote the answer to that question, I'll just mark this one as a duplicate so people can get their answer.

Comment: @NicE Sounds good to me!